# How to detect corrupted files?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery

I messed up recovery of a corrupted HDD; part of the hard drive now has corrupted random files.

I can't go manually through each file and open it, so I'm looking for a way (software?) that will tell me which files are corrupt. There are zip files videos and image files.

Some files inside a folder have recovered properly but the rest have not. These last files are taking up a lot of space and I want to delete them.

Comment: @EricF some files,particularly zip and compressed files, usually have built-in CRC or similar checksums built-in for each file.

Comment: @cybernard How do you access what the checksum should be and what it currently is? Wouldn't you need a "good" version of the file to do this?

Comment: @EricF I used 7zip from 7zip.org simply because it is easier to get them.  Open any zip file in 7zip, and there they are: https://i.imgur.com/YV7T5G7.png   The CRC is stored in headers that are very small, and many dozen can fit in a single cluster.  If you can locate part of the ZIP file they are **most likely** not corrupted.  The CRC-32 is generated when the file is added to the zip, and isn't modified unless the file changes.  Take the CRC-32(or etc) and take the data you think is the file compute the checksum(CRC-32 or etc) and if they match the file is intact.

Comment: @EricF Different types of files have different built-in mechanism to at least identify if the file is OK. Older file types like TXT,BMP basically have none, other than looking at it to see if it looks right. The newer file types have at least some kind of checksum, but sometimes go further than that.
See 3.2  Each chunk of a PNG has a CRC checksum which can be verified.
https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html

Comment: @EricF, well no... The point of a CRC is that it can be used to verify if the file is consistent or broken. Other formats, such as JPG, can be decoded and the tool spits an error if the decoding fails.

Comment: related: folder disappear but still take space (how to fix corrupted files on the drive that are invisible --not just hidden) https://superuser.com/questions/1583213/folder-disappear-but-still-take-space-how-to-fix-corrupted-files-on-the-drive-t/1583214#1583214

Answer (score 2):

```
So I have wondering if there is some software out there that will detect if a video file or a zip file is corrupt?
```

ZIP files can be verified with ease.  Most ZIP software will offer the option but I am going to demo, opensource, 7zip.

[image: 7zip open with CRC]

Click the **Test** button

[image: No errors found]

Each file has a unique CRC stored also

[image]

Finally individual files or groups of file can be checked

[image]

Even if a file has errors it maybe worth looking at it because it may still have usable contents.  This test is an **exact** **pass** or **fail** test.  In almost every case an error of even 1 bit will cause a fail.